# 2 dimensions on same axis Tableau

Tags: bar-chart, tableau-api, dimensions

I am trying to plot 2 dimensions into a bar chart. So I have data that looks at what products customer buy there are 5 different types of product and I have them from 2 different stores. so the data looks like which are stored in 2 different excel files.

```
Store 1
customer_ID product
1           apple
1           orange
2           apple

Store 2
customer_ID product
1           apple  
1           orange 
2           pear
```

I'd like to be able to be able to have product on the x axis and then count on the y axis. with the 2 different stores in different colours. Is it possible to do this in Tableau or do I need to rearrange my data into 1 table that is like

```
customer_ID product store
1           apple   1
2           orange  2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in tableau indeed.  I have created two excel files named Store1 and store2 with sample data.

You should do like this

Import first file in Tableau.  Thereafter, double click New Union button

[image]

In the WildCard dialog type Store*.xlsx

[image]

Your Union is created automatically, with file name
[image]

You can now easily proceed to create a view as desired.  In case of any problem further, do tell me.

[image]